# Bootstrap 4 Mega Menu on hover

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm looking to build a mega menu hover in bootstrap 4 just exactly like the one in the image below
[image]

I've looked at few examples online however, they do not match my requirement as im looking for a full width on hover megamenu exactly as you can see in the image.

I have tried the following

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Category 1
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="text-uppercase text-white">Category 1</span>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/ccc/000&text=image+link" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
            <p class="text-white">Short image call to action</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--  /.container  -->
    </div>
</li>
```

This does not give me full width dropdown and way far from my need.

Is there anyone who has tried bootstrap 4 and who can help me generate a menu exact like in the image.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Category 1
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu container-fluid" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="text-uppercase text-white">Category 1</span>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/ccc/000&text=image+link" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
            <p class="text-white">Short image call to action</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And put some css for hover effect.

```
<style>
  .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
     display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Dropdown hover is working with your css but what about the mega menu. How to achieve it like in the picture.

Comment: I also want to make sure that other dropdowns do not get affected

Comment: Remove container div and use the container-fluid class with the dropdown-menu class. It will open the drop-down menu in full screen.

Comment: Create your own class and apply css on them so the other menus does not get affected.

Comment: I tried your css it shows the menu when hovered but im unable to click on the menu dropdown items as it dissappears if i move the cursor away from the link(Category 1 in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Category 2
                
                
                  Active
                
                
                  Link item
                
                
                  Link item
                
              
              
              
              
                
                
                  Active
                
                
                  Link item
                
                
                  Link item

```
            </a>
            <p class="text-white">Short image call to action</p>

          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-4  -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--  /.container  -->
```